# Possible bug in xstring + pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, xstring, bugs

**Question refined considering the replies…**

In macro `\StrCut`, if the first argument contains a “ç”, we get an error message.  The same happens with ”\c{c}” or capital “Ç”.  When replaced with a plain “c” there is no error.
No error ever with XeLaTeX nor LuaLaTeX.

I beleive `\noexpandarg` does not allow the source string to be a macro name.

It works (no error) for other accented characters like "ã", "á", etc…
It works for German "ß".
It does not work for "ç".
I admit it is not an error, but this particular behavior for "ç" seems odd to me!

Example triggering the error:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\myname}{João,is,good}
  \StrCut{\myname}{,}\partone\parttwo
  [\partone][\parttwo]
  \renewcommand{\myname}{Straße,is,good}
  \StrCut{\myname}{,}\partone\parttwo
  [\partone][\parttwo]
  \renewcommand{\myname}{Açai,is,not,good}
  \StrCut{\myname}{,}\partone\parttwo
  [\partone][\parttwo]
  \renewcommand{\myname}{Açai,is,good,but,not,good}
  \noexpandarg\StrCut{\myname}{,}\partone\parttwo
  [\partone][\parttwo]
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you mean `%` rather than `##` here?  I can't see how you can avoid an error from `#` in text?

Comment: This is not a bug, it is documented behaviour of xstring

Comment: But it is an odd behavior, working with some accented characters (á, ã) and not with others (ç). :(

Comment: well it says it passes the arguments through `\edef` by default. `\edef` will basically destroy most latex commands including accented characters. If some manage to survive that's by luck not design. (the package probably should use `\protected@edef` rather than `\edef`, but it doesn't as it is not written for latex) You can usually use expl3 functions rather than xstring, but it depends what your use case is. Oh I just noticed @egreg posted expl3 versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a bug. You may use `\noexpandarg`, but there are other ways.

You can reimplement most (all) of `xstring` in `expl3`. Here's `\StrCut`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xStrCut}{mmmm}
 {
  % #1 = tokens
  % #2 = separator where to split at
  % #3 = macro where to store the first part
  % #4 = macro where to store the second part
  \joao_xstrcut:nnNN { #1 } { #2 } #3 #4
 }

\seq_new:N \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joao_xstrcut:nnNN
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq { #2 } { #1 }
  \tl_clear_new:N #3
  \tl_clear_new:N #4
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq #3
  \tl_set:Nx #4 { \seq_use:Nn \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq { #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xStrCut{Açai,is,good}{,}\partone\parttwo

[\partone][\parttwo]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version where you can use a macro for the first argument. You need to use `\xStrCut*`, in this case. I think that overloading is bad.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xStrCut}{smmmm}
 {
  % #1 = optional *
  % #2 = tokens
  % #3 = separator where to split at
  % #4 = macro where to store the first part
  % #5 = macro where to store the second part
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \joao_xstrcut:VnNN #2 { #3 } #4 #5
   }
   {
    \joao_xstrcut:nnNN { #2 } { #3 } #4 #5
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq
\tl_new:N \l_joao_strcut_head_tl
\tl_new:N \l_joao_strcut_tail_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joao_xstrcut:nnNN
 {
  \tl_if_exist:NF #3 { \tl_new:N #3 }
  \tl_if_exist:NF #4 { \tl_new:N #4 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq { #2 } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq #3
  \tl_set:Nx #4 { \seq_use:Nn \l_joao_strcut_parts_seq { #2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joao_xstrcut:nnNN { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xStrCut{Açai,is,good}{,}\partone\parttwo

[\partone][\parttwo]

\newcommand{\mytext}{Açai,is,good}

\xStrCut*{\mytext}{,}\partone\parttwo

[\partone][\parttwo]

\xStrCut*{\parttwo}{,}\parttwo\partthree

[\parttwo][\partthree]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This new `xStrCut` does not work if the source string is in a macro. See the refined examples above. Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoLourenço I added a version that accepts a macro as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks @egreg.  You made my day.  :)

Answer (score 8):

In luatex or xelatex `ç` is a simple character token like `c`,  but in pdflatex it is a pair of tokens that expand to `\c{c}`. `xstring` by default passes its arguments through `\edef` which would break any such command but it has a `\noexpandarg` switch to prevent this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
  \noexpandarg
  \StrCut{Açai,is,good}{,}\partone\parttwo % #### No error when "Acai"
  [\partone][\parttwo]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use `\noexpandarg` with the source string in a macro? See refined example. Thanks!